# Fonts with ambiguous / similar characters

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I'm looking for a font with *deliberately* ambiguous Latin characters.

i.e. where symbols like O0, 8B, Il1, 5S, 2Z, 6b, 9g, are either identical or visually indistinct.

Certain fonts like Arial have some degree of ambiguity - but I can't find a font which is specifically designed to have as many homographs as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet will probably handwritten fonts. The indiscriminate and visual lack of precision will help your cause. I gave a quick search through my own font collection and these were the closest I found:

- Architect's Daughter
- Bauhaus 93 Regular
- CityBlueprint Regular

The best I found was [Architect's Daughter](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Architects+Daughter) from Google Fonts:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Century Gothic is one. And other Futura variations, so I prefer to call them. I would say, Bauhaus also belongs there.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_Gothic

[image]